# Java hashMap NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have two hashMaps :

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> attributesCountPerCategory;
```

and

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> attributesCount;
```

I also have the method:

```
public void increaseAttributes(String attr, String category){
    HashMap<String, Integer> attributes = this.attributesCountPerCategory.get(category);
    if (attributes == null) {
        this.attributesCountPerCategory.put(category, new HashMap<String, Integer>());
        attributes = this.attributesCountPerCategory.get(category);
    }

    Integer c = attributes.get(attr);
    if(c == null){
        attributes.put(attr, 0);
        c = attributes.get(attr);
    }
    attributes.put(attr,c++);

    Integer c2 = this.attributesCount.get(attr);
    if(c2 == null){
        this.attributesCount.put(attr,0);
        c2 = this.attributesCount.get(attr);            
    }
    this.attributesCount.put(attr,c2++);        
}
```

So when I am calling this method a `NullPointerException` is thrown even though I am checking for `null` values in object references. The exception is thrown in the below line:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> attributes = this.attributesCountPerCategory.get(category);
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: can you post the stack trace of the NPE

Comment: You haven't shown us where the exception is thrown, nor anything that initializes `attributesCountPerCategory`.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: `attributesCountPerCategory` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because in this line

```
HashMap<String, Integer> attributes = this.attributesCountPerCategory.get(category);
```

attributesCountPerCategory has not been initialized. This is why it is null.

to fix either do

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> attributesCountPerCategory = new HaspMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> ();
```

or initialise it at some other point prior to calling it